# Linux: how to replace file names from a file containing original patterns and new patterns?

Tags: linux, filenames

if you have 4 files named SampleA.txt, SampleB.txt Samble25.txt and SampleA21.txt. 
And that you have a tab-delimited txt file where one column has the original pattern (SampleA, SampleB, Sample25, SampleA21) and another column with corresponding new pattern (Community1, Community2, Community3, Community4),

is there a way to change the files title from the original pattern (first column) to the new patter (second column)?

Comment: did you see: https://askubuntu.com/q/283145?  might be useful if you've only got a few patterns…

Comment: Hi Sam! Thanks yes i saw it. Unfortunately I would like something that can convert it no matter how many there are objects and how different are the Objects, as long as in one file is listed the original pattern of the file name and its New pattern. But thanks!

Answer (score 0):

just had a quick hack in Python, maybe something like this would be useful:

```py
#!/bin/env python3

from sys import argv
from pathlib import Path
import csv

with open('rename-pats.txt') as fd:
    inp = csv.reader(fd, delimiter='\t')
    patterns = []
    for src, dst in inp:
        patterns.append((src, dst))

for path in argv[1:]:
    path = Path(path)
    name = path.name
    for src, dst in patterns:
        name = name.replace(src, dst)
    if path.name != name:
        path.rename(path.with_name(name))
```

relies on a file called `rename-pats.txt` containing something like:

```
SampleA Community1
SampleB Community2
Sample25    Community3
SampleA21   Community4
```

which would then be run as:

```sh
python3 mmv.py *.txt
```